# Ng-class not working

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="TestingCtrl">
    <input ng-class="{'fancy' :status}">
    <input ng-class="{'fancy' :status2}"> 
    <input type="button" value="change" ng-change="action()">
 </div>


.fancy{
  background:Yellow;
}

function TestingCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.status = true
    $scope.status2 = true

    $scope.action = function() {
        $scope.status = false
        $scope.status2 = false
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you expect that does or doesn't happen?

Comment: class is not added for element

Comment: Did you initialize the angular app? Did you add the controler to the app? Just having a function called SomeController won't be sufficient.

Comment: The answers below correctly diagnose why `ng-change` is not working (no `ng-model`). Props to them, just want to suggest an alternative to using `ng-click`: add `ng-model` to the input so that `ng-change` then works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model never changes so ng-change is never called. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

"ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model"

The action function is never evaluated because there's no ng-model to change for that specific input.

If you do ng-click it will work, then you can toggle the background color.

```
$scope.action = function(){
    $scope.status = !$scope.status
    $scope.status2 = !$scope.status2
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYk2c/

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-click instead of ng-change on button and it's done.. Also Created an angular app first before your controller..

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function testController($scope) {

$scope.status = true;
$scope.status2 = true;

$scope.action = function() {
    $scope.status = false
    $scope.status2 = false
}
```

}

and the html goes like this

```
<div ng-controller="testController">

    <input ng-class="{'fancy' :status}">
    <input ng-class="{'fancy' :status2}"> 
    <input type="button" value="change" ng-click="action()">

</div>
```